# How to traceroute a site behind a VPN on a Mac?

Tags: networking, vpn, traceroute

I am trying to use `traceroute` on MacOS 12.4 but I do not get any useful output it seems. I am trying to get the traceroute to a resource behind a VPN.

The output is

```
$ traceroute  -d -I my.domain.com
traceroute to my.domain.com (1.2.3.4), 64 hops max, 72 byte packets
 1  some.domain (10.2.3.4)  55.562 ms  43.052 ms  65.707 ms
 2  some.domain2 (11.2.3.4)  55.562 ms  43.052 ms  65.707 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  my.domain (1.2.3.4)  55.562 ms  43.052 ms  65.707 ms
```

How to use this command to find a bottleneck in the routing? I tried some different options, but I always get 5 lines of stars (`* * *`) in between some routers.

How to make any sense of this? How to find the bottleneck in a connection if the slow routers are stared out? What domains are they? Why is it not printed?

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=traceroute+asterisks

Comment: @Gantendo I don't think so

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Gantendo I did not find anything related/helpful under your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not get any useful output it seems [snip]. How to make any sense of this? Why is it not printed?

Traceroute is working correctly, those are routers that don't respond to IMCP messages. They won't be "printed" ([please check my answer to your second question](https://superuser.com/questions/1727559/how-to-see-unresponsive-servers-in-a-traceroute/1727561#1727561)).

> How to find the bottleneck in a connection if the slow routers are stared out?

You can not find or rather fix a bottleneck on the internet, routing is supposed to "fix itself" if certain routes are slow. You can only fix bottlenecks on routers you have access to.

If the bottleneck is "somewhere on the internet" you can try to use a different internet connection (e.g. mobile) hoping that it takes a different route, contact your ISP (the problem might be on their infrastructure), or wait for the problem to fix itself.

> What domains are they?

You are probably confusing routers with servers, routers don't need a domain in order to work, they just pass along your IP packets to the next router (and eventually to the destination server).

PS. Please don't double post!