# How to see unresponsive servers in a traceroute?

Tags: networking, traceroute

When you do a `traceroute` and a router does not respond within a timeout then traceroute prints an asterisk, like

```
traceroute my.domain.com
...
13  te9-2.dsr01.dllstx3.networklayer.com (70.87.253.14)  40.037 ms  24.063 ms
te2-4.dsr02.dllstx3.networklayer.com (70.87.255.46)  28.605 ms
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  zyzzyva.site5.com (174.122.37.66)  20.414 ms  20.603 ms  20.467 ms
```

But what are the names of the servers in step 14&15, or their IP adresses? How to print them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.

Oversimplified traceroute uses ping with a reduced TTL value starting with 1 (usually your router) and going up until it gets to the target server thus getting responses from all the servers in between. You can regard a server with an asterisk as a server that doesn't respond to ping so there will be no information available.

For a more in-depth explanation just check the results of your favorite search engine e.g. [here](https://ipwithease.com/how-traceroute-works/)

It might be possible to use different tools or parameters like tcptraceroute, `traceroute -T`, etc. (check Bib's comment) but they don't necessarily give you better results.

Comment: I do agree, but sometimes you can get more info. Try tcptraceroute and target either port 22 or 443. Doesn't always work though.

Comment: @Bib yeah correct, thanks for the addition, I had some luck using `traceroute -T` as well in the past